# "SafeValue must use [property]=binding:" message in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a html object (parent object) defined as follows:

```
<app-new-message [message]="msg.Htmltext></app-new-message>
```

In the child object, when I use that message definied in the parent object I have defined:

```
@Input() set message(value: string){
    if (value != ''){
      this.newMessage.message = '\n\n\n' + value;
    }
  }
```

But when I execute the app I get this message in the child object when showing the message:

**SafeValue must use [property]=binding:
"text message"**

Any help to avoid this warning message?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the string you pass contains html tags.

Angular will give out this warning/error because those tags could potentially be dangerous and inserted by an attacker.

Same goes for web-links, Angular will be blocking those if you do not previously sanitize them.

Read more about it here: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

To fix the warning, first inject the DomSanitizer in your component/service:

```
constructor(private readonly _sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}
```

then sanitize the value:

```
public safeValue: SafeHtml;
this.safeValue = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.msg.Htmltext);
```

and pass the safeValue to the other component:

```
<app-new-message [message]="safeValue"></app-new-message>
```

You can write a pipe that does this for you:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml' })
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private readonly _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  public transform(html: string): SafeHtml {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
 <app-new-message [message]="msg.Htmltext | safeHtml"></app-new-message>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Trying both of the two first approaches I get the following message in the child component where I show the content: "msg.Htmltext" but is not showing the real content of the parent component. If I use the last approach I get the warning message described in my post.

Comment: The first 2 approaches are used to pass strings as input, the last one is used to pass properties as input. Please include more information, espescially what `msg.Htmltext` is. Also include a picture of the full warning if possible.

Comment: I use my code for reply a message in a messages system. I just want to send the text for printing it in the new reply message box. The msg.Html text is just html text formatted (it contains html tags).

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, see my updated answer.